# vector emplace_back requirements and unique_ptr members

Tags: c++

The following code does not compile (at least in the versions of g++/clang I tried). [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/g/gZY784)

```
struct T {
    std::unique_ptr<double> p;

    T() {}
    T(const T&) {}
    T(T&&) {}
};

struct X {
    T t;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> f;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<X> y;
    X x;
    y.emplace_back(std::move(x));
}
```

Specifically, the compilers seem to complain about a call to a deleted copy constructor on `vector<unique_ptr<int>>` which doesn't make sense to me.

The [requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) seem to more or less say that `emplace_back` should work if there is a move constructor. Since there are no user-declared constructors for `X` and also no members / base classes that can't be moved from, I believe that a move constructor should be implicitly declared and not deleted.

Some 'fixes':

- [remove the `T` member](https://godbolt.org/g/vyXxUr)
- [remove the `vector<unique_ptr<int>>` member](https://godbolt.org/g/BkC9g3)
- [add another `unique_ptr`](https://godbolt.org/g/pgWUHA)
- define move constructor explicitly for X

Could someone explain why the original code is ill-formed? And why the 'fixes' (mostly the first 3 and especially the 3rd) make the code compile?

Comment: Fix #5: Make `T`s move-constructor noexcept.

Comment: @tkausl yes... I forgot about that caveat for vector operations... it doesn't seem to explain 'fix' 2 or 3 though.

Comment: @Praetorian yes I forgot about the move noexcept qualifications but the question you linked doesn't answer my full question either. From the emplace_back reference: 'If T's move constructor is not noexcept and is not CopyInsertable into *this, vector will use the throwing move constructor.'

Comment: #2 and #3 is somewhat more subtle, I assume vector chooses move even if its not noexcept if copy is impossible and the vector of non-copyable objects reports back as being copyable and fails when it actually tries to copy it. Not sure what exactly is going on interally though.

Comment: By the way, this might seem like a problem arising from the emplace_back trying to move in the object, it isn't. Its about the vector making sure it's large enough and reserve more space if needed.

Comment: @Lawrence That clause doesn't apply to `X`, it is copyable and has a throwing move constructor so `vector` will attempt to copy it. Adding the extra `unique_ptr` to `X` makes the class non-copyable, so `vector` is forced to use the move constructor, throwing or not.